# What is wrong with this QuickSort implementation?

Tags: javascript, sorting, computer-science, quicksort

I have the following:

```
function quickSort(array, low, high) {
    var len = array.length,
        l = low || 0,
        r = high || len - 1,
        m = Math.round((l + r) / 2),
        t;

    do {
        while (array[l] < array[m]) {
            l += 1;
        }
        while (array[r] > array[m]) {
            r -= 1;
        }

        if (l <= r) {
            if (l < r) {
                t = array[r];
                array[r] = array[l];
                array[l] = t;

                console.log('Swapped ' + array[r] + ' with ' +
                                         array[l] + '. ' +
                                         array);
            }

            l += 1;
            r -= 1;
        }
    } while (l <= r);

    if (r > 0) quickSort(array, 0, r);  
    if (l < len - 1) quickSort(array, l, len - 1);
}
```

Using it as follows:

```
var initial = [1, 8, 9, 0, 2, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 10], // Duplicate, just to compare
    sorted  = [1, 8, 9, 0, 2, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 10];

quickSort(sorted);

console.log('Initial: ' + initial + '\nSorted:  ' + sorted);
```

Surprisingly, the code throws `stack_overflow` after the array was sorted. I guess I am missing the recursion exit condition, but I don't know where.

Comment: Have you tried to sort the list manually (by hand) and see if the "Swapped"-log lines match. Maybe you could add some comments to the code (for example why do you have two almost identical if's nested?).

Comment: @Lycha, yes, the swap cycles match. When we arrive at `if (l <= r)` condition it means that we have an element on the `l`eft side that is greater than the separation element `m`. Likewise, we also have an element `r` which is smaller than `m`. Therefore, we swap them unless they are equal and increment (and decrement) the corridor margins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit (replacing previous answer)**: I believe the issue here is the way you're setting the `len` variable. For an in-place sort, the `len` should only be the length of the portion of the array being sorted, not the entire array, or your comparisons at the end will never evaluate to false. So instead of:

```
var len = array.length,
    l = low || 0,
    r = high || len - 1;
```

You need to set `len` based on `l` and `r`:

```
var l = low || 0,
    r = high || array.length - 1,
    len = r-l;
```

You can see the working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/PPeh9/6/ - I replaced your test data with a random array for testing.

Comment: No, in this case the right part of the array won't be sorted at all — at the end of the `do … while` loop `l` will be equal to either `m - 1` or `m`. You can check it in the fiddle you have provided — the partially-sorted array has 8 after 9.

Comment: @Honneykeepa - you are correct, sir. I'll take another look at this - I do think that's where the logic's off though.

Comment: @Honneykeepa - see my updated response. The logic *was* off here, but it was because of how `len` was set, not what you were comparing.

Comment: This is definitely an improvement! Upvote. However, the function does not sort the array appropriately. @nrabinowitz, thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Curses, you're right again. This is turning into a crash course in quicksort. I'll take another look. (Out of curiosity, you do know that `array.sort()` will probably be significantly faster, right?)

Comment: I have finally figured out what was wrong: I have separated `l` and `r` variables from `high` and `low`; changed `m`, so that it did not refer to the pivot element, but stored its value; and, of course, used your recommendations.

Comment: Yes, I know that native `.sort` is faster. I tested and `quickSort` took around 1850 ms, while `Array.sort` coped in nearly 450 ms :(